# How to terminate a hung akka actor?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I'm writing my HelloWorld for Akka, I have fixed (20 to 50) number of actors created in a Main Actor, half of them are simple counters, another half calculates factorial and sums results in some way.
The main goal was to test how Akka handles naughty hung threads. I added Thread.sleeps with semi-random time to my threads and defined a timeout by scheduling special ForceShutdown case.

What I **wanted** to get:

- 1) Main Actor receives StopMessage, collects results from
  child-actors and gives them the PoisonPill
- 2) Once all the results are collected, main Actor shuts down the
  system
- 3) If the results are not collected during the timeout, a
  ForceShutdown case is firing up, killing everything and shuts down
  the system by force.

What I got:
1 and 2 are working right, but:

- 3) Once ForceShutdown is fired, MainActor is still waiting for
  children to finish their work, it doesn't terminate them.

I tried several variants of ForceShutdown case, but most of them work just the same, waiting for the child actor to finish unfinished work.
Here's an example:

```
case ForceShutdown =>
  println(s"[${self.path.name}] ForceShutdown received!")
  children foreach { child => system.stop(child) }
  system shutdown
```

So, how to force terminate hung actors in Akka?

Comment: In actor model, you don't *terminate* somebody, you kindly ask somebody to stop. This is the reason why your code does not work -- relevant excerpt [from the doc](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/untyped-actors.html): *Processing of the current message, if any, will continue before the actor is stopped, but additional messages in the mailbox will not be processed ... If one of the actors does not respond (i.e. processing a message for extended periods of time and therefore not receiving the stop command), this whole process will be stuck*.

Comment: So, your actor is locked in processing current message and it does not know that somebody wants it to stop. No idea how to force it, though. And, by the way [YDIW by spawning actors solely to send off actual processing](http://www.chrisstucchio.com/blog/2013/actors_vs_futures.html), unless they perform some staged processing.

Comment: thanks for your comment, though I bet it should be an answer. So, there's no way to shutdown an application if there is a hung actor. A simple solution comes to my mind: if some processing inside actor is hung-dangerous, I can wrap it with Future/Await, that has it's timeout. In this way I'd be guaranteed that no actor will be hung. I should try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the JVM there is no way to forcefully shut anything down, since terminating something within the same process will likely corrupt shared state and lead to a broken application. Your idea with the Future will appear to work at first, but the thread pool that runs your runaway code will not shut down, meaning that the JVM will not stop or will accumulate defunct thread pools and eventually run out of memory.

As a consequence you should design all your actors to stay responsive: if you need to run long processing tasks you should break them up into short steps that the actor sends to itself. That way a termination request will be honored in due time.

Answer (score 0):

akka is totally async process. even the `Kill` message needs to wait until the current task is done. it's just `Kill` takes highest priority so the mailbox queued messages will be ignored, instead `PoisonPill` is like normal message and will be processed last. so queued messages got to be processed gracefully before the actor got shutdown.